Annotation with nested and dynamic forms?
I am trying to label data where a piece of text can have any number of top level labels, and for each of those, it can have any number of child labels. For example, the text might be a description of a family. When I am labeling, I should be able to enter any number of family members' names. And for each family member, I should be able to enter any number of hobbies as well as any number of previous jobs.
After labeling, I would export them as JSON objects.
I installed Label Studio, but I haven't yet been able to find tags that allow dynamic repeating. Where it might have a space for a person's name, and a  button for adding another person.
Does anyone know if this can be done in Label Studio, or if any other software (preferably free) supports this?
